# Replace/Change array value with another array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays.

```
<?php 
       //Array 1
       $txt_bln[]   = array($bln_txt => 0);
       echo json_encode($txt_bln)
       //the result :[{"Januari":0},{"Februari":0},{"Maret":0},{"April":0},{"Mei":0},{"Juni":0},{"Juli":0},{"Agustus":0},{"September":0},{"Oktober":0},{"November":0},{"Desember":0}]

       //Array 2
       $data_bln_2[]    = array($bln_txt_2 => (int)$results_jmlh['total']);
       echo json_encode($data_bln_2)
       //the result :[{"April":1},{"Oktober":1},{"Desember":8}]

?>
```

How can I modify Array 1 based on Array 2. The result will become like this:

```
//the result :[{"Januari":0},{"Februari":0},{"Maret":0},{"April":1},{"Mei":0},{"Juni":0},{"Juli":0},{"Agustus":0},{"September":0},{"Oktober":1},{"November":0},{"Desember":8}]
```

then change it into php array. The final output :

```
[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,8]
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what your tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$previous=json_decode('[{"Januari":0},{"Februari":0},{"Maret":0},{"April":0},{"Mei":0},{"Juni":0},{"Juli":0},{"Agustus":0},{"September":0},{"Oktober":0},{"November":0},{"Desember":0}]',true);   
//replace json value with your variables 
$current=json_decode('[{"April":1},{"Oktober":1},{"Desember":8}]',true);
//replace json value with your variable 
$latest=array();
$modified_latest=array();
foreach($previous as $p)
{
    $found=false;
    foreach($current as $c)
    {
        if(key($p)==key($c))
        {
            $latest[]=$c;
            $modified_latest[]=$c[key($c)];
            $found=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!$found)
    {
        $latest[]=$p;
        $modified_latest[]=$p[key($p)];
    }

}    
echo json_encode($latest);
//outputs : [{"Januari":0},{"Februari":0},{"Maret":0},{"April":1},{"Mei":0},{"Juni":0},{"Juli":0},{"Agustus":0},{"September":0},{"Oktober":1},{"November":0},{"Desember":8}]

 print_r($modified_latest);
 //outputs :Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 1 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 [8] => 0 [9] => 1 [10] => 0 [11] => 8 ) 
 //that means : [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `array_merge` ?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

```
array array_merge ( array $array1 [, array $... ] )
```

> Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.
>
> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.
>
> Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.

If you want to forget your string keys to get numeric keys, I guess your looking for `array_values`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

```
array array_values ( array $array )
```

> array_values() returns all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically.